# Rails ActiveRecord: PG::Error: ERROR: column reference "created_at" is ambiguous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, join

I am struggling with the error in object and not sure at all where is the problem.

This is how the models looks like:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :car_colors
  has_many :colors, :through => :car_colors
end

class CarColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :car
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :car_colors
  has_many :cars, :through => :car_colors
end
```

Here is the query:

```
@cars = Car.all(:joins => :car_colors, :conditions => { :car_colors => {:color_id => params[:id_number]}}, :order => "cars.created_at DESC")
```

And the error output:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...d" WHERE "car_colors"."color_id" = 2 AND (created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "car_colors" ON "car_colors"."car_id" = "cars"."id" WHERE "car_colors"."color_id" = 2 AND (created_at > '2013-05-03 12:28:36.551058') ORDER BY cars.created_at DESC
```

The generated SQL query (below the error message) seems to be fine, but what causes the error message?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing missing from the query you posted? No conditions on the associations or anything? Something is applying a date condition but nothing in the query should do that.

Comment: Yes, I am completely sure. That's why is the error so weird.

Comment: Similar question, check it out.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885335/rails-has-many-through-pgerror-error-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous-err/15885379

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There likely is a created_at field in your `car_colors` table. `created_at` should probably be `cars.created_at` to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: I am just checking the `car_colors` migration and yes, there is `t.timestamps` - but why is this problem? Anyway, I will try to remove it. What do you mean by the second sentence?

Comment: It's a problem because PG can't know whether you're meaning `created_at` for `cars` or `car_colors`... SQL is not a language that gives any room to ambiguity: either the statement is clear with no possibility of interpretation, or it is not and should get rejected with the error message that you're seeing.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `AND (created_at > '2013-05-03 12:28:36.551058')` appears in the SQL, removing the timestamp is not a solution, it just glosses over the problem.

Comment: @Matt: agreed, but we're likely missing the bits and pieces of the code that makes it appear.

Comment: This is called perfect answer

Answer (score 28):

Define a scope like this:

```
scope :scope_age, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

rather than:

```
scope :scope_age, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
```

It removes the ambiguity by using the property of the model in which the scope is defined in.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. I was getting "undefined method 'gsub' for {:name=>:asc}:Hash" when I tried `order(name: :asc)`. However, I was able to get `order("users.name ASC")` to work.

Thanks for the inspiration that got me to my answer!

Comment: And if the scope is using a multi-column where?

Comment: the definition `default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }` cause me the same issue, fixed it by removing it or changing to `default_scope { order(created: :desc) }`

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove your timestamps from the join model, they aren't the problem - the problem is that something is adding a condition to your query:

```
AND (created_at > '2013-05-03 12:28:36.551058')
```

Since the date is one month ago, search your code for `one.month.ago` and see if it appears in any scopes, probably in your cars or car_colors models. Check the scopes manually if nothing turns up through the search.

Removing the timestamps will make your query work, but it's not the right thing to do.

Comment: I was getting a similar error (different column) but it turned out to be a sort column. Thanks for the inspiration!