# Ambiguous 'id' column error - Rails/Postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**Not a dupe. I added why at the bottom of the question.**

I have two models, `Playlist` and `User`, which both have_many of and belong_to each other through a third table `PlaylistUser`.

For a certain Playlist `@playlist`, I want to print a list of all other Playlists that share Users with `@playlist`. Ideally, this list would be ordered by how many Users they share.

This query is meant to do that, but it results in an error:

```
Playlist.joins(:users).where.not(id: @playlist.id).where(users: {id: @playlist.user_ids}).group(:id).order('count(*) desc')
```

**Model**

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

I think the problem is that Rails doesn't know which `:id` column I'm referring to.

How can I resolve this?

Here's the error I get when I run the query in the console:

```
> @playlist = Playlist.first
> Playlist.joins(:users).where.not(id: @playlist.id).where(users: {id: @playlist.user_ids}).group(:id).order('count(*) desc')

(415.0ms)  SELECT "users".id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = $1  [["playlist_id", 1]]
Playlist Load (74.2ms)  SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE ("playlists"."id" != 1) AND "users"."id" IN (15, 73, 77, 128, 76, 93, 119, 94, 112, 120, 579, 567, 568, 569, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 609, 603) GROUP BY id ORDER BY count(*) desc
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...3, 609, 603) GROUP BY id  ORDER ...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE ("playlists"."id" != 1) AND "users"."id" IN (15, 73, 77, 128, 76, 93, 119, 94, 112, 120, 579, 567, 568, 569, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 609, 603) GROUP BY id  ORDER BY count(*) desc
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...3, 609, 603) GROUP BY id  ORDER ...
                                                         ^
: SELECT "playlists".* FROM "playlists" INNER JOIN "playlist_users" ON "playlist_users"."playlist_id" = "playlists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "playlist_users"."user_id" WHERE ("playlists"."id" != 1) AND "users"."id" IN (15, 73, 77, 128, 76, 93, 119, 94, 112, 120, 579, 567, 568, 569, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 609, 603) GROUP BY id  ORDER BY count(*) desc
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:798:in `async_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:798:in `exec_no_cache'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:138:in `block in exec_query'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:442:in `block in log'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:437:in `log'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:915:in `select'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:25:in `select_all'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:64:in `select_all'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/querying.rb:36:in `find_by_sql'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/relation.rb:587:in `exec_queries'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/relation.rb:471:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/relation.rb:220:in `to_a'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.10/lib/active_record/relation.rb:575:in `inspect'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.0.0-p643 :008 >
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885335/rails-has-many-through-pgerror-error-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous-err). I updated my model.rb files like so:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('playlists.id ASC') }
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :users, :through => :playlist_users
end

class PlaylistUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('playlist_users.id ASC') }
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('users.id ASC') }
  has_many :playlist_users
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlist_users
end
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails has\_many :through PG::Error: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885335/rails-has-many-through-pgerror-error-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous-err)

Comment: I know isnt exact but maybe that help

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I tried that solution but it didn't work.

Comment: I would suggest that you first get all the users (ids) of `@playlist` with `@playlist.user_ids` and then do something like `Playlist.joins(:playlist_users).where(user_id: @playlist.user_ids).group(:playlist_id).count(:playlist_id)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with your grouping. Which `id` do you want to group by? Since you have joined two tables, each with an `id`, postgres does not know which one to pick.

You could try changing `group(:id)` to `group('playlists.id')` or `group('users.id'`). Whichever one you want the grouping to be done on.